# jquery checkbox sumbit - multiple forms?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I'm using this to submit values from a single form when a checkbox is clicked. The form is called my-form.

```
$( '#my-form input[type=checkbox]' ).click( function() {
    $.post(
        'form.php',
        $( '#my-form' ).serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            $( '#my-form #form-response' ).html( response );
        }
    );
} );
```

This is working fine for one form. But I'd like to have other forms, maybe 10 on the same page and re use this code.

I understand each form has to have a unique ID, but how do I submit just that form, not any of the others ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

give all of your forms same class and do it like this

```
$( '.my-form input[type=checkbox]' ).click( function() {
    var CurrectForm=$(this).parents('.my-form:first');
    $.post(
        'form.php',
        CurrectForm.serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            CurrectForm.find('#form-response').html( response );
        }
    );
} );
```

`my-form` is the class name for all forms.

Comment: You don't need to wrap `CurrentForm` in the jQuery selector every time; you've already created the jQuery object on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the ids to classes, and just submit the parent form of the checkbox, like so:

```
$( '.my-form input[type=checkbox]' ).click( function() {
    var $my_form = $(this).closest('.my-form');    

    $.post(
        'form.php',
        $my_form.serialize(),
        function( response ) {
            $( '.form-response', $my_form ).html( response );
        }
    );
} );
```

Comment: form-response is id not class

Comment: IDs should only be defined once. `.form-response` is inside each form, therefore it must be a class, not an ID.